# Already responsive div container, how to make a responsive background image with perfect scale

Tags: css, background-image, responsive

How can I have a perfect scale [background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF3y9.png), if the div box already is scaled with `width : 100%`? If I try `background-image : 100% 100%`, the background image is too stretched out.

Here's my css code for the header which the background image is in:

```
.header-main-bar {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(BerlinFrontpage.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: If you use the background-size:contain your image will be displayed in the div showing the entire image (kinda like keeping the aspect ratio), while adjusting it to the largest side of the image (i.e., width or height), that will fit.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but contain i have already tried and the image wont fit the div-container.. here the link to the background image in the header : https://urban-garden24.webshopapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to give atleast the height: auto; because otherwise it wont scale properly.

(Am besten wäre es wenn du dein Beispiel mal mit Codepen.io posten würdest. Dann könnte man dir noch eher helfen.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `background-size:cover;`